# Error : Connection timed out: connect ? While building project gradle

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am getting error while building the gradle (IDE tool version 3.1.3 android)
android version : 3.1.3
gradle version : 4.4
Not able to download files below when gradle sync 
Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom  21s 215ms

Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom  1m 24s 138ms

Download http://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.3/gradle-3.1.3.pom  21s 84ms

> Error : Connection timed out: connect

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Is there any solution for this guys

Answer (score 0):

[image]Are you working behind a proxy?

try to run

```
./gradlew assemble --debug --info --stacktrace
```

And share your log information please.

Besides that, check your ***gradle.properties*** to see if you have any proxy configured? If you are not behind any proxy, please remove those settings.

Also, please be sure that "`google()`" repo is added and put as the first inside your `buildscripts` block. E.g.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //jcenter() //Should remove this repository for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0+, and use google() repository as shown below
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: No just compiling the project

Comment: #shizhen any solution for this

Comment: i will attach log file

Comment: have you tried this command?    ./gradlew assemble --debug --info --stacktrace